# Logging Key and Mouse events in java

Tags: java, events

I would like to capture key strokes and mouse events being entered into a different window, eg such as a browser. What is the best approach to doing this, and no i dont want to be sneaky and capture bank account passwords.

I appreciate that this requires JNI in order to setup some hooks and the like with the current host OS. I could not find any premade java library that had this facility which is odd given that Java has libraries for everything.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of job is OS dependent and there is no cross-platform way to do it with Java.